# Collapsing toolbar with Additional Information and viewpager

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

[image]

I want to design a layout like above image with Collapsing toolbar Effect, I have already tried collapsing toolbar with viewpager but with that I can add only Image and viewpgaer, I want to add the below information and then viewpager, please help me here, if anyone have any idea.

Thank you so much in advanced !!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/collapsing_tool_bar_margin_end"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/collapsing_tool_bar_margin_bottom"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/collapsing_tool_bar_margin_bottom">


         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coverImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
             app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/slidingTabs"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: I have shared my code, please check above code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add different view inside your collapsing toolbar like:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:id="@+id/header_layout"
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                          android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                          android:layout_gravity="bottom|left">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="Title"
                          android:textColor="#ffffff"
                          android:textSize="25dp"/>
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="subtitle"
                          android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Adjust the textsize,margin,and the rest as you wish.

But then add a this code to make sure that your added layout fades in when the toolbar collapses

```
headerLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header_layout);

AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
```

And make your activity class **implement** AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener

Then your **onOffsetChanged** method should be like this.

```
 @Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int offset) {
    float scaleFactor=1+(offset*0.005f);
    if(!(scaleFactor<0)){

        headerLayout.setAlpha(scaleFactor);
    }
    if(scaleFactor<0.3){
        headerLayout.setAlpha(0);
    }

}
```

Adjust the float value "0.005f" for the desired effect.

I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

I changed theme to solve this issue:

you should use ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light;